# Can anyone identify this eMMC card socket?

Tags: memory

It's not mSATA or PCI-e mini card. Any ideas what socket this eMMC fits into?

[image]

Comment: What is on the other side of the card?

Comment: http://www.maximumpc.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&p=1340134&sid=138f8e2916c583f7acb780d9588b3d97 bit more context here.

Answer (score 2):

Why? If you don't know what it is... what are you expecting to do with it?

The device's part number is printed in plain view...

This is a [**SanDisk SDIN7DP4-64G**](http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2013/3/3/7/13/47/322/sndk_/manual/sdin7dp4-16g.pdf) 169-Pin [eMMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard#eMMC) 64GB flash device on a board.

http://www.sandisk.com/products/embedded/inand/inand-extreme/

*iNAND Extreme is an Embedded Flash Drive (EFD) designed for mobile handsets and consumer electronic devices. iNAND Extreme is a hybrid device combining an embedded thin flash controller and standard MLC NAND flash memory, with an industry standard e.MMC 4.51 interface.*

The full product PDF is available [here](http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2013/3/3/7/13/47/322/sndk_/manual/sdin7dp4-16g.pdf).

The socket doesn't look familiar, but we're missing details here: Where did you get it? What do you intend to do with it?

But it could be anything. I've seen this type of thing in automotive, copiers/MFPs, phone systems... Can you provide more context?

Comment: Perhaps he found it in a spare parts bin?

Comment: Sure I know what is it .. question is, what is the the industry standard for the socket - that's my opening question. I know it's intended for embedded devices and very likely to be in tablets or other portables, I just haven't seen one like this. I got it from a junk collector friend which means I have no idea what it is intended for, but for a 64gb NAND, that's plenty for proper use instead of going to the trash.